# error TS2416: Property '_registry' in type 'MockMatchMedia'

Tags: angular, angular7

After [updating my Angular 6.1 application to Angular 7](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c), I get this error with `ng serve`:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(25,15): error TS2416: Property '_registry' in type 'MockMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
  Type 'Map<string, MockMediaQueryList>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, MediaQueryList>'.                 
    Type 'MockMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.                                         
      Property 'onchange' is missing in type 'MockMediaQueryList'.                                                
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(63,22): error TS2420: Class 'MockMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.                                           
  Property 'onchange' is missing in type 'MockMediaQueryList'.                                                    
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(80,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.                                                                              
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/mock/mock-match-media.d.ts(82,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.                                                                              
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(11,22): error TS2420: Class 'ServerMediaQueryList' incorrectly implements interface 'MediaQueryList'.                                            
  Property 'onchange' is missing in type 'ServerMediaQueryList'.                                                  
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(28,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.                                                                                 
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(30,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MediaQueryListListener'.                                                                                 
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(42,15): error TS2416: Property '_registry' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.          
  Type 'Map<string, ServerMediaQueryList>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, MediaQueryList>'.               
    Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.                                       
      Property 'onchange' is missing in type 'ServerMediaQueryList'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/match-media/server-match-media.d.ts(54,15): error TS2416: Property '_buildMQL' in type 'ServerMatchMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'MatchMedia'.
  Type '(query: string) => ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type '(query: string) => MediaQueryList'.
    Type 'ServerMediaQueryList' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update to `@angular/flex-layout 7.0.0-beta.19`  or better:

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout@^7.0.0-beta.19
```

No need to report; this is [a known issue](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/851).